# FFmpeg watermark duration

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, android-library

I am developing an Android app, which will work with FFmpeg library which only applies multiple watermarks on some test.mp4 video. For that case I am using the Android java library for FFmpeg binary from that source: [http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/] which is working fine for some examples, but I just can not use commands like these:

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4 -vf "movie=/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4 [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10, fade=in:0:20 [out]" /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4
```

Please note these quotes after -vf flag and these [in], [logo] flags. These just throw me an errors like

```
[NULL @ 0xb5bf3200] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[logo];'
[logo];: Invalid argument
```

and so on. The quotes in the command are also the problem which throws me an error like:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xb5c092c0] No such filter: 'overlay=main_w-50:main_h-50,overlay=0:0'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument".
```

Am I even using proper library for that case? I also want to show the watermark in specific duration of the video. For example if video is 10 seconds long, I only want watermark to be shown starting from 3rd second of the video to 7th second. I can show the overlay images like this:

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg -filter_complex overlay=main_w-50:main_h-50,overlay=0:0 -codec:a copy /storage/emulated/0/Download/test_edited.mp4
```

but they're shown for the whole video duration. Where can I set the duration start/end for the specific overlay?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Android users often seem to have issues with quotes. Try without quotes.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you're right it works without quotes, but [logo] and [in] stuff still doesn't work. Do you know something about duration of overlay? Thank you very much

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not descriptive enough for me to provide any suggestions. I'm guessing you're now experiencing a different issue. You need to update your question and show your new command and the complete console output/log.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard actually I already did mention that in the question: ... Unable to find a suitable output format for '[logo];' ...